# Selenium take element screenshot - Google Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to take screenshot of a `<canvas>` tag element from google chrome using selenium web driver and python.

I tried using the below code,

```
driver.find_element_by_css('#canvas-xyz').save_screenshot('canvas.png')
```

It returned

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'save_screenshot'
```

I also tried this in dev tools,

```
document.querySelector('#canvas-xyz').toDataURL()
```

It returned the following DATA URI, which is empty.

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Is it possible to take screenshot of an element using chromedriver and selenium in python. I am aware that chrome dev tools allows us to take screenshot of a particular element. Even if it is a JavaScript method also i can get the data URI using `driver.execute_script()` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebElement` doesn't have `save_screenshot`. You can use `screenshot_as_png` (property) and save it

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css('#canvas-xyz')
scrrenshot = element.screenshot_as_png
with open('canvas.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(scrrenshot)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why `element.save_screenshot('file.png')` doesn't work on chrome ?

Comment: @CodeIt `WebElement` doesn't have `save_screenshot()`

Comment: if I use find_element_by_class_name, element.screenshot_as_png doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebElement.screenshot()`method:

```
def screenshot(self, filename):
    """
    Saves a screenshot of the current element to a PNG image file. Returns
       False if there is any IOError, else returns True. Use full paths in
       your filename.

    :Args:
     - filename: The full path you wish to save your screenshot to. This
       should end with a `.png` extension.

    :Usage:
        element.screenshot('/Screenshots/foo.png')
    """
```

So, in your example, that would be:

```
driver.find_element_by_css('#canvas-xyz').screenshot('canvas.png')
```